# How to install devoloper version or any other version of an application using git?

Tags: git, github, installation, archlinux

I need to install gns3-server 2.1.10dev2 version from GitHub https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-server To install regular version i use tag, checkout and setup script.`git tag --list`  `git checkout v2.1.9` and then `sudo python3 setup.py install`
I want to install 2.1.10dev2 version, i can't checkout the version as there is no tag. How do I install that version?

Comment: Are you sure that there is branch named `2.1.10dev2 ` or a tag `2.1.10dev2 ?` If not you can always checkout a commit hash. Find out the commit hash that you need and directly checkout that commit.

Comment: No, I only knew that there was '2.1.10dev' version of the application where the bug is fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__version__ = "2.1.10dev2"` was set in the commit [089d25c](https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-server/commit/089d25c79d8abfc957243c7b4ffc6be9c077ada7#diff-6b2cefdc7d9af252c10241f0a4f08bac). There are more than 10 commits since then in the branch [2.1](https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-server/commits/2.1). You have to decide which of these commits you want to build, check it out and build.

You can simply build the latest commit in the branch:

```
git checkout 2.1
python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, installed the `2.1.10dev2`version